# Не работают некоторые компоненты Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

По каким-то причинам не работает. В консоли огромная ошибка. Вроде бы делаю также как и в официальной документации. Кто может дать ответ?

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",

  data: {
    eventInfo: "click"
  },

  methods: {
    someEvent: function() {
      console.log("Hello!");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <p v-on:[eventInfo]="someEvent"></p>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: покажите ошибку

Answer (score 2):

Ты пытаешься сделать динамический v-on, но у него другой синтаксис: v-on="{ someEvent: someAction }"

Ответ на твой вопрос [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44776751/vuejs-dynamic-v-on-event-possible).

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",

  data: {
    eventInfo: "click"
  },

  methods: {
    someEvent: function() {
      console.log("Hello!");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <button v-on="{ [eventInfo]: someEvent }">Click!</button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
```